# Trying to learn Python; code leads to infinite loop and I can't figure out why?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python and I am trying to run a random walk that plots the points. I have tried de-bugging this myself but I cannot figure out where this is going wrong. I apologise since this seems like a really simple problem but I am getting frustrated.

One file rw_visual.py sets things up and then calls the other file random_walk.py to generate the points in the walk.

**rw_visual.py:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQiv.png)

**random_walk.py:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQiv.png)

In debugging, rw_visual.py seems to run until it tries to run the command "rw.fill_walk()" and then it hangs. This tells me that there is something wrong in the while loop in random_walk.py causing this. As hard as I try, I cannot figure it out thought.

Sorry for the very basic question.

Comment: can you paste the code instead of screenshotting it?

Comment: **Do not post code as images**, as it's hard to run and inspect it. Please [edit] your question and format the code properly.

Comment: The two pictures refer to the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here but your while loop condition is always true. You are not changing `self.x_values` so it's length is always 1 and is always <  `self.num_points` which is always 50.

Comment: Please, paste your code. **Don't post code as images.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python indentation implies scope.  By getting the indentation of your `while` loop (and all it should contain) correct, I think this is producing the results you're looking for I left out the "graphical" part and just printed the x and y coordinates as a result of the random walk.  You can take over the graphical part from here.

```
from random import  choice

class RandomWalk():
    def __init__(self, num_points=50):
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
            x_direction = choice([1, -1])
            x_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance
            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance
            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue
            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            print (str(next_x) + " " + str(next_y))

            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)

rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()
```

### RESULTS

```
-2 -3
1 0
-2 0
-1 1
-1 -3
1 -1
4 0
0 0
0 4
0 5
3 5
1 3
1 4
1 3
-2 4
-3 7
0 7
1 7
-2 5
-2 1
-3 1
-1 0
-4 3
-3 5
0 9
3 7
3 4
-1 5
1 8
4 10
6 11
6 7
9 9
13 10
12 10
12 11
9 9
12 10
16 11
15 7
14 6
14 3
16 2
18 2
15 0
13 -2
12 -1
8 1
12 1
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I will post the actual code next time also.